# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded on predeployment of PersistenceUnit

Tags: java, garbage-collection, glassfish, payara

I'm working on a web project with Java EE, and it works smooth on my computer, but when I export into a war and upload it into the server I'm receiving the following error:

```
[2017-02-01T23:29:09.439+0100] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=40 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool(1)] [timeMillis: 1485988149439] [levelValue: 800] [[
  ================== availabilityEnabled  skipped]]

[2017-02-01T23:31:07.548+0100] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-REST-00003] [javax.enterprise.admin.rest] [tid: _ThreadID=5211 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool(143)] [timeMillis: 1485988267548] [levelValue: 800] [[
  An error occurred while processing the request. Please see the server logs for details.
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer$ResponseWriter.rethrow(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:324)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer$ResponseWriter.failure(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:306)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:509)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
]]

[2017-02-01T23:31:08.403+0100] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=38 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1485988268403] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jpa/querydef/CriteriaQueryImpl.class of size 21034
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
]]
```

In my computer, it works without any problem, with a stable memory usage around 450,000Kb - the jvm allowed memory in the server is 512Mb, is there a problem in the server or could be something in my code? as I can only see references to glassfish and sun libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you receive an OutOfMemoryError, the stacktrace is not relevant at all. The code in the stacktrace just requires allocation of additional memory, but the memory can be consumed by objects created somewhere else.

Investigate which objects consume the memory, for example using a profiler, VisualGC or analyze the heap dump. In particular, seek for classes defined in your application, which have an unusually high number of instances in memory.

Also, think what might be different between the 2 environments. Is it possible that the application reads data from DB during deployment, and the data in DBs differ?

The usage of 450MB on your local computer is quite close to the limit of 512MB - it is possible that the server consumes more memory than your local server, because of the different server configuration. Compare how much memory is consumed by the server and your local server before you try deploying the application.